# Планировщик задач Open Server запуск *.bat

Tags: mysql, cron, dump

Ввожу в планировщике путь:

```
%progdir%\backup\CreateBackup.bat
```

Выбираю */2, каждые 2 минут.

В логе OpenServera пишет:

```
03 Mar 13:21:09 Start nnCron
03 Mar 13:21:09 Load cron.tab
03 Mar 13:22:00 Start: f:\openserver\backup\CreateBackup.bat
03 Mar 13:22:18 Start result: 0
03 Mar 13:24:00 Start: f:\openserver\backup\CreateBackup.bat
03 Mar 13:24:02 Start result: 0
03 Mar 13:26:00 Start: f:\openserver\backup\CreateBackup.bat
03 Mar 13:26:00 Start result: 0
03 Mar 13:28:00 Start: f:\openserver\backup\CreateBackup.bat
03 Mar 13:28:00 Start result: 0
```

Батник запускается отдельно и работает. Но через планировщик не хочет

Comment: `cmd.exe /c %progdir%\backup\CreateBackup.bat` ?

Comment: Попробую: %COMSPEC% /c %progdir%\backup\CreateBackup.bat

Comment: Нет, тоже самое. Попробую в путь указать  %COMSPEC% /c и команду из батника

Comment: Если же пишу командой %COMSPEC% /c %realprogdir%\modules\database\%mysql_driver%\bin\mysqldump.exe -A -a --opt --host=%ip% --user=root > %progdir%\backup\dump\%DD%_%MM%_%YYYY%_%hh%_%mm%.sql то все работает, а надо чтобы через батник

Comment: Тогда `cmd /k ...` - при этом окно командного процессора не закроется, и можно (нужно!) посмотреть 1) выводимые сообщения 2) от имени какой учётной записи запущена консоль.